# Initializing a 2d array of custom class in java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, polymorphism, multidimensional-array

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to instantiate a class that contains a 2d array of interface.
In a other class i have an Object of type CompetitionGround and i try to do something like this to initialize it:

```
CompetitionGround groud;
ground=new CompetitionGround(5);
```

My constructor for the class CompetitionGround looks like this:

```
public CompetitionGround(int boundries) {
    for (int i = 0; i <boundries; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <boundries; j++)
            eggs[i][j]=new Egg();
}
```

and the whole class is:

```
public class CompetitionGround {

    private IEgg eggs[][];

    public void goIn(Rabbit rabbit) {
        IPozition temp = rabbit.getPozition();
        rabbit.Collect(eggs[temp.getPozitionX()][temp.getPozitionY()]);
    }

    public CompetitionGround(int boundries) {
        for (int i = 0; i < boundries; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < boundries; j++)
                eggs[i][j] = new Egg();
    }

    public void AddEgg(int x, int y, int points) {
        eggs[x][y] = new Egg(points);
    }
}
```

Class Egg that implements IEgg has two types of constructors. I tried with both and get the same problem. What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Grammar advice: Its spelled `Position` not `Pozition` and `boundaries` not `boundries`

Comment: It looks like you're accessing a null element, `eggs`, just like the error states. Initialize `eggs`. Don't forget to contemplate the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't ever initializing `eggs`, which is causing your issues. Right now you are initializing each element of `eggs`, but that will give you problems if you don't initialize `eggs` itself first.

I recommend doing this in the constructor like this:

```
public CompetitionGround(int boundries)
{
    //Remember, you want IEgg, not Egg here
    //This is so that you can add elements that implement IEgg but aren't Eggs
    eggs = new IEgg[boundries][boundries];

    for (int i = 0; i <boundries; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <boundries; j++)
        {
            eggs[i][j]=new Egg();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, this is unrelated, but boundaries is spelled wrong. Could cause problems later.

Comment: Awesome! Also please consider accepting this answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The array itself was never initialized, so you can't assign anything to its elements yet.  Before initializing in the 2 nested `for` loop, create the 2D array itself first.

```
public CompetitionGround(int boundries  /* [sic] */) {
    // Init array here.
    eggs = new IEgg[boundries][boundries];

    // You should use proper indenting.
    for (int i = 0; i < boundries; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < boundries; j++)
           eggs[i][j] = new Egg();
}
```

Comment: This solution is not polymorphic

Comment: @asrivat1 For some reason I didn't see `IEgg`.  Updated.

Comment: Thanks, your  explanation helped a lot!I was trying one thing or  the other ,didn't even think to use both.